# Python: What's the equivalent of String[a:b] but for Unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, string-formatting

So I have something like this:

```
x = "CЕМЬ"
x[:len(x)-1]
```

Which is to remove the last character from the string.
However it doesn't work and it gives me an error. I figured it's because it's Unicode. So how do you do this simple formatting on non-ansi strings.

Comment: Why is unicode an issue here? This does not look like a unicode string. Apart from that: strings are immutable.

Comment: @Maulwurfn: because it's a byte string in python 2, not a unicode string, thus the OP is slicing bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 6):

That's because in Python 2.x `"CЕМЬ"`, is a strange way of writing the *byte* string `b'C\xd0\x95\xd0\x9c\xd0\xac'`.

You want a *character* string. In Python 2.x, character strings are prefixed with a `u`:

```
x = u"CЕМЬ"
x[:-1] # Returns u"CЕМ" (len(x) is implicit for negative values)
```

If you're writing this in a program (as opposed to an interactive shell), you will want to [specify a source code encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). To do that, simply add the following line to the beginning of the file, where `utf-8` matches your [file encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: or use `\uxxxx` unicode escape literals for anything that's not an ASCII character (python 2). In py3k, the default source code encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

save the file with `utf-8` encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
x = u'CЕМЬ'
print x[:-1]  #prints CЕМ
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = u'some string'
x2 = x[:-1]
```